# Pyrebase: Firebase callback is not called when database is large

Tags: firebase, pyrebase

`db.child("root/child_1").stream(callback, None)` works perfectly when `child_1` contains only a few items (~200), but the callback is never called (not even once when the stream is invoked first) when we have ~2000 entries under child_1.

I'm using Pyrebase. I'm not sure if this is a Pyrebase problem or a firebase problem.

Comment: Are you using the realtime database or firestore?

Comment: @temp_ I am using the real-time database

Comment: Take a look at the [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it takes about 15 minutes to get the first snapshot when the number of records in the DB is ~2000.